# How do I find the folders after the 6/14/2017 Google Drive update?

Tags: shared-folders, google-drive, user-folders

I'm unable to find the Google Drive folders after updates were made on 6/14/2017.  They are visible from my Google Nexus phone.  How can I make them show up in Google Chrome?  I see files when doing a search, in "Recent" files, and some show up as quick access icons under "Google Drive".

Answer (score 0):

Click "Refresh" on the Google Chrome browser, and they will magically appear on all subsequent times you access Google Drive!